# Python - List conversion of sliced iterable increases with every slice

Tags: python, iterator, generator, python-itertools, chunking

I have a generator from read_sql and convert this generator to iterator using itertools.islice. So I convert this generator to iterator in slices using start and stop arguments. And this process runs in a loop to convert generator to iterator in 3 slices and convert the iterator to a list.

First time when it runs -> `iterable_slice = list(it.islice(generator_df, 0 , 3))` takes 2.99 seconds
Second time when it runs -> `iterable_slice = list(it.islice(generator_df, 4 , 6))` takes 5.3 seconds
and with every new loop or next set of slices, list conversion takes more time.

Why does this happen and where I am making a mistake? Thoughts please. Thank You.

```
#function to convert generator to slices

def gen_to_itr(generator_df,slice_start,slice_end):
    iterable_slice = list(it.islice(generator_df, slice_start,slice_end))

#main function 
slices = 3
slice_start = 0
slice_end = slices
flg_cnt = 0
while slice_end <= bcnt and flg_cnt <= 1:
    generator_df = pd.read_sql(query2, test_connection_forbankcv_connection, chunksize = 1800)
    first = time.perf_counter()
    iterable_slice = gen_to_itr(generator_df,slice_start,slice_end)
    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Chunk list created in {round(end-first, 2)} second(s)')
    slice_start = slice_start+slices
    .....
```

Comment: Are you sure the time is coming from creating the iterator rather than performing the query?

Comment: Positive, its the same query that runs every time. It is nothing to do with performing the query i believe. Also started the timer after query generator and results are same.

Comment: `list(it.islice(generator_df, 4 , 6))` fetches and discards four items from `generator_df` before yielding any items. It does more work than `list(it.islice(generator_df, 0 , 3))` which doesn't have to skip before yielding.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Thank you. This makes sense. But i broke down this list(it.islice(generator_df, 4 , 6)) into two lines. First the sliced iterator it.islice(generator_df, 4 , 6)  and the the list conversion list(iterable). It appears first step-sliced iterator creation takes same time (seconds) every loop but it is the LIST CONVERSION that takes time and time increases with every loop /new sliced iterator. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

`it.islice()` has to skip over the first `slice_start` elements of the generator when creating the new iterator. This takes time proportional to `slice_start`.

However, I find it hard to believe that skipping each element of a pandas series would take about 1 second. If the chunksize were smaller than the slice sizes, it might need to do another fetch from the database to get the next chunk. But as long as you're in the same chunk, I think it should have the same speed as iterating through a static series.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense. But i broke down this list(it.islice(generator_df, 4 , 6)) into two lines. First the sliced iterator it.islice(generator_df, 4 , 6) and the the list conversion list(iterable). It appears first step-sliced iterator creation takes same time (seconds) every loop but it is the LIST CONVERSION that takes time and time increases with every loop /new sliced iterator. Thoughts?

Comment: `islice()` might defer skipping the elements until the first time it's called to generate an element.

Comment: Python is open source, why don't you look at the implementation of `islice`?